# Why delete query only delete one record

Tags: mysql

Hi I’ve got the folowing query:

```
DELETE tickets, archive, files
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN ticket_files
ON ticket_files.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN archive
ON archive.document_id = ticket_files.document_id
LEFT JOIN files
ON files.file_id = ticket_files.file_id
WHERE tickets.ticket_id = 21
```

When the ticket doesn’t have any record in the junction table ticket_files then the ticket is deleted correctly but if there is more than one record in the ticket_files then only one record is deleted from the tables archive and files. How can i make sure all the joined records are deleted also from archive and files? many thanks

This is the database structure. As you can see the ticket with ID 1 has got two files associated in the ticket_files table but ticket with ID 2 doesn't have any files associated.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:8889
-- Generation Time: Mar 28, 2022 at 07:35 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.34
-- PHP Version: 8.0.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `archive`
--

CREATE TABLE `archive` (
  `document_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `document_sent_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `document_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `document_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `document_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=public 0=draft',
  `document_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=no 1=yes',
  `document_note` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `archive`
--

INSERT INTO `archive` (`document_id`, `document_sent_by`, `document_description`, `document_category`, `document_status`, `document_featured`, `document_note`) VALUES
(23, 1, 'File one', 7, 1, 0, 'File one'),
(24, 1, 'File two', 7, 1, 0, 'File two');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `files`
--

CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `file_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=public 0=draft',
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `files`
--

INSERT INTO `files` (`file_id`, `file_name`, `file_type`, `file_size`, `file_date`, `file_category`, `file_status`, `file_path`) VALUES
(23, '1648496062', 'application/pdf', '9514', '2022-03-02 00:00:00', 7, 1, '/docs/1648496062.pdf'),
(24, '1648496079', 'application/pdf', '146367', '2022-03-09 00:00:00', 7, 1, '/docs/1648496079.pdf');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tickets`
--

CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_sent_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `building_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_object` text NOT NULL,
  `ticket_priority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=aperto 2=lavorazione 3=chiuso',
  `ticket_comments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0=no 1=yes',
  `ticket_visibility` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=public 0=draft',
  `ticket_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=no 1=yes',
  `ticket_private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT ' 0=no 1=yes ',
  `ticket_open_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ticket_edit_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tickets`
--

INSERT INTO `tickets` (`ticket_id`, `ticket_sent_by`, `building_id`, `ticket_subject`, `ticket_object`, `ticket_priority`, `ticket_status`, `ticket_comments`, `ticket_visibility`, `ticket_featured`, `ticket_private`, `ticket_open_time`, `ticket_edit_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 13, 'Ticket with files', '<p>this ticket has files<br /></p>', 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, '2022-03-28 20:33:59', NULL),
(2, 1, 13, 'Ticket with no files', '<p>ticket with no files<br /></p>', 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, '2022-03-28 20:35:02', NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ticket_files`
--

CREATE TABLE `ticket_files` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `document_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ticket_files`
--

INSERT INTO `ticket_files` (`ticket_id`, `document_id`, `file_id`) VALUES
(1, 23, 23),
(1, 24, 24);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `archive`
--
ALTER TABLE `archive`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`document_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `files`
--
ALTER TABLE `files`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tickets`
--
ALTER TABLE `tickets`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `ticket_files`
--
ALTER TABLE `ticket_files`
  ADD KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
  ADD KEY `document_id` (`document_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `file_id` (`file_id`);

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `archive`
--
ALTER TABLE `archive`
  MODIFY `document_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=25;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `files`
--
ALTER TABLE `files`
  MODIFY `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=25;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tickets`
--
ALTER TABLE `tickets`
  MODIFY `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- Constraints for table `ticket_files`
--
ALTER TABLE `ticket_files`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_files_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_id`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`ticket_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_files_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`document_id`) REFERENCES `archive` (`document_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_files_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id`) REFERENCES `files` (`file_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Set correct foreign keys and use cascade deletion.

Comment: Why are doing a LEFT JOIN on ticket_files when you aren't deleting from that table and aren't using any data from it?

Comment: if you want help please post the table definitions as text

Comment: Hi @Kendle I've edited the question and added the database tables as requested. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add `ticket_files` to the list of the tables in the DELETE:

> ```
> select * from ticket_files;
> ```
>
> ```
> ticket_id | document_id | file_id
> --------: | ----------: | ------:
>         1 |          23 |      23
>         1 |          24 |      24
> ```

> ```
> DELETE tickets, archive, files, ticket_files
> FROM tickets
> LEFT JOIN ticket_files
> ON ticket_files.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id
> LEFT JOIN archive
> ON archive.document_id = ticket_files.document_id
> LEFT JOIN files
> ON files.file_id = ticket_files.file_id
> WHERE tickets.ticket_id = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from ticket_files;
> ```
>
> ```
> ticket_id | document_id | file_id
> --------: | ----------: | ------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1bae7f4148b735fd67e4bca4c96041d9)*

Comment: Hi @kendle thanks for your help your query does work well to remove the ticket if no files associated to it but if the ticket has two files associated (two rows in archive and files tables) then only one row is deleted in archive and files tables. Also sometimes I get the following error: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Comment: Try adding `OR document_sent_by = 1` to the WHERE clause?

Comment: Hi, the column document_sent_by is related to the user table by coincidence in this case has got same ID of the ticket. I believe the only way to sort this out is to change database structure adding a new table "tickets_archive" and in this table add a colum "ticket_id" with on delete cascade. Otherwise If I keep the actual structure then I will have to make to queries first one to check if the ticket_id has got values in the ticket_files table and then if there are values delete from junction table if not then delete only from tickets table